# Compare two datasets in two different data tables using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Please tell me how to compare two datatables in two different datasets.I have got one data table having 5 columns in one data set and another datatable having 2 columns in other dataset. Column 1 in both the data tables should be same. I have to compare 1st column in both the datatables in different datasets. If the both the rows are same it should keep a flag saying yes or no, in the third column in datatable 2. And also it should merge the other columns say 2,3,4 and 5 from datatable 1 in dataset1 to datatable 2 in dataset2.

Both the datatables I am importing the values from excel workbook which are having multiple worksheets. So one worksheet to one datatable. Similarly two workbooks are there.

1st datatable in 1st dataset will be like

A    B    C    D   E

1    2    3     4   5

2    3    4     5   6

3    4    5     6    7

2nd datatable in 2nd dataset will be like

A   F

1   2

2   3

3   4

The output datatable 2 in 2nd dataset should be like

A   B    C   D   E   F   G

1   2    3    4   5   2  YES

2   3    4    5   6   3   YES

3   4    5    6   7   4  YES

Please suggest me how to proceed, I am trying to learn vb.net

Thanks in Advance

Jithin

Comment: Can you explain the columns in the result table more and the logic behind?

Answer (score 1):

You could

- [define a primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on both DataTables
- create a new DataTable with all columns
- loop through all rows in DataTable 1 and use the pk to look up the "matching" row in DataTable 2
- insert a row in the new DataTable for each result

Then you'll need some additional logic to find all those rows that are only present in DataTable 1 or 2 if you also want those rows in the new DataTable.

Did you consider changing the way you fill both datatables? If this is the result of 2 queries, perhaps you could use a join statement in your SQL?

Comment: I am a novice in VB.net coding. Can you please guide me how to create a primary key through vb.net?

Comment: Notice how `define a primary key` is a link. I don't want to sound patronizing but _what have you tried_?

Comment: After defining primary key how can we do the connection string part?Beacuse i just know how to pass one connection string like dim dt1 as new oledb.oledbdataadaptor("Select * from [Sheet1$]",myconnection), here myconnection will be the one for the first dataset right?how can i do the update function with both the data tables?

Comment: You need to look into the "JOIN" SQL statement. (assuming you are getting your data from a Relation Database). It would look like: `SELECT sh1.FIELD, sh2.FIELD2 FROM [Sheet1$] sh1 JOIN [Sheet2$] sh2 ON sh1.PK=sh2.PK`